# Behavior of cells in Jtable (right click inside of a cell)

Tags: java, swing, jtable, cell

I have a `JTable` and I want to open a PopupMenu by a right-click inside a cell. I tried this by making my own `AbstractCellEditor`, but it doesn't work (When I start my program and when the first method initialize the `CellEditor` (it´s the last thing that this method do), `CellEditor` is starting. But at the beginning of the next method the `CellEditor` has already disapeared). Can somebody please help me? I´m trying to find the error for weeks.

This is the Code of `CellEditor`:

```
public class CellEditor extends AbstractCellEditor implements TableCellEditor {

    JTextField component;
    JPopupMenu popmen;

    CellEditor(){
        component = new JTextField();
        popmen = new JPopupMenu();

        createPopmen(component);
        component.addMouseListener(new MouseAdapter(){   
            public void mouseReleased(MouseEvent e) {
                if ( e.isPopupTrigger() )
                      popmen.show( e.getComponent(), e.getX(), e.getY() );
               }
        });  
    }

    public Component getTableCellEditorComponent1(JTable table, Object value,
            boolean isSelected, int rowIndex, int vColIndex) {      
        if (isSelected) {      
        }

        component.setText((String)value);
        return component;
    }

    public Object getCellEditorValue() {
        return component.getText();
    }

    @Override
    public Component getTableCellEditorComponent(JTable arg0, Object  arg1, boolean arg2,int arg3, int arg4) {
        return null;
    }


public void createPopmen(final JTextField text){

    // creating Popmen

}

}
```

This is the part of the code, where something is happening with my table:

```
Vector<Vector> nu = new Vector<Vector>();
Vector<String> columnNames = new Vector<String>();
TableModel model;


model = new DefaultTableModel(nu, columnNames){
          public Class getColumnClass() {
              Class returnValue;
              if ((3 >= 0) && (3 < getColumnCount())) {
                System.out.println(getValueAt(0, 3));
                returnValue = getValueAt(0, 3).getClass();
              } else {
                returnValue = Object.class;
              }
              return returnValue;
            }                   
                 public boolean isCellEditable(int row, int col) {
                     if(col == 0){
                         return false;
                     }
                     else{
                         return true;
                     }

                 }
          };

    table = new JTable(model);      
    final TableRowSorter<TableModel> sorter = new TableRowSorter<TableModel>(model);
    table.setRowSorter(sorter);
    table.putClientProperty("terminateEditOnFocusLost", Boolean.TRUE);
    table.getSelectionModel().addListSelectionListener(new ListSelectionListener(){
          public void valueChanged(ListSelectionEvent e){
                int a = table.getSelectedRow();
                if (!changes.contains(a) && a!=-1 && table.getSelectedColumn() != 0){
                    changes.add(a);
                    saved = false;
                }   
          }
    });



    // SearchingBar
    textfield.addKeyListener( new KeyListener(){

        @Override
        public void keyPressed(KeyEvent arg0) {

        }
        @Override
        public void keyReleased(KeyEvent arg0) {

            String searchedText =textfield.getText();       
            if (searchedText.length() == 0) {
                sorter.setRowFilter(null);
              } else {
                sorter.setRowFilter(RowFilter.regexFilter(searchedText));
              }
        }
        @Override
        public void keyTyped(KeyEvent arg0) {       
        }       
    });

    ((DefaultTableModel) model).removeRow(0);
    table.setModel(model);
    table.setCellEditor(new CellEditor());
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There should be no need to create a custom editor. You should be able to do something like:

```
JTable table = new JTable(...);
DefaultCellEditor dce = table.getDefaultEditor(Object.class);
Component editor = dce.getComponent();
editor.addMouseListener(...);
```

Also, read the section from the Swing tutorial on [Sorting and Filtering](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/table.html#sorting) for a working example of how to use filtering. You should not be using a KeyListener.

If you need more help then post your [SSCCE](http://www.sscce.org) which demonstrates the problem.